# Erro ao dar build em qualquer protejo no Qt Creator

Tags: qt, compiladores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento dar build em qualquer projeto no Qt, dá essa mensagem de erro
(teste com um dos exemplos que já vem com o Qt)

```
13:15:37: Running steps for project analogclock...
13:15:37: Could not start process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\examples\gui\analogclock\analogclock.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Error while building/deploying project analogclock (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'qmake'
13:15:37: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Eu tenho o compilador funcionando perfeitamente no code::blocks.
Já reinstalei o Qt diversas vezes e já fiz a instalação executando como administrador.

Se alguém tiver a solução ou ao menos explicar o erro eu agradeço.
Sou estudante de Eng. Mecatrônica - 3ª fase